# Is UEFI returning a false memory map or has QEMU an error?

Tags: qemu, osdev, uefi

I have a bootloader written with UEFI. I use `-m 100M` when running QEMU and I excpected to have about 100M of memory when using `BS->GetMemoryMap();` But I got about 350M which is weird. Following is the code I used to get the memory map:

```c
static efi_status_t memory_map(efi_memory_descriptor_t **map_buf, uintn_t *map_size, uintn_t *desc_size) {
    *map_size = sizeof(**map_buf) * 31;

get_map:
    *map_size += sizeof(**map_buf);

    efi_status_t ret = BS->AllocatePool(EfiLoaderData, *map_size, (void**)map_buf);
    if (ret != EFI_SUCCESS) {
        ST->ConOut->OutputString(ST->ConOut, L"ERROR: Failed to allocate pool for memory map\n\r");
        return ret;
    }

    uintn_t _empty;
    uint32_t _empty2;
    ret = BS->GetMemoryMap(map_size, *map_buf, &_empty, desc_size, &_empty2);
    if (ret != EFI_SUCCESS) {
        if (ret == EFI_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL) {
            BS->FreePool((void*)*map_buf);
            goto get_map;
        }

        ST->ConOut->OutputString(ST->ConOut, L"ERROR: Failed to get memory map\n\r");
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Source: https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2012/08/uefi-memory-v-e820-memory.html

I don't get any error messages so is there an error in the function or is it weird behavior of QEMU? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Please add your full qemu command line, what firmware you're running, and the method you use to determine you have 350M of memory.

Comment: @unixsmurf There is no other parameter except the -drive and the UEFI firmware as it says in my post. I use a for-loop for counting the memory size: 'out += desc->size'